Does enabling compression in thrift helps memory bandwidth bottleneck if you have low cpu util and network util?
If you compressed your thrift request, does it help lower memory bandwidth
For example my understanding of the data flow is this

client send ztsd compressed request
server get compressed request
compressed data is in network buffer
compressed data is in NIC
compressed data is in memory
compressed data is uncompressed by cpu
uncompressed data is store back in memory
uncompressed data is used by cpu
uncompressed data is compressed by cpu
compressed data is sent to NIC
compressed data is sent to network buffer

vs

client send request
server get request
data is in network buffer
data is in NIC
data is in memory
data used by cpu
data is sent to NIC
data is sent to network buffer

it would seem that ztsd compression only helps on network IO and not memory bandwidth util
is my understanding correct?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
